# Getting Latest Value from Prestashop DB

Tags: mysql, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to retrieve a value with a WHERE clause but it is not working at the moment.

```
$query= new DbQuery();
$query->select('id_carrier')
->from('carrier')
->where('name = ' . "'XXX'");
$carrier_id = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue($query);

print $carrier_id; //returns the first value found
```

Currently, it is returning the first value but I will need to use the latest as for every change done in Prestashop carrier, the ID will change. Thus, I will need to get the latest value.

I was checking and found out about (int)Db::getInstance()->Insert_ID(); but I have tried it and it is not working too.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's an Id with auto increment, in a normal usage situation the greatest id will also be the last inserted, you can use:

```
$query= new DbQuery();
$query->select('max(id_carrier)')
    ->from('carrier')
    ->where('name = ' . "'XXX'");
$carrier_id = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue($query);
```

The Insert_ID() only works if the carrier (in this case) was inserted in the current connection. And only retrieves the last one. Basically, if it was just inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work with the codes below:

```
$query = new DbQuery();
$query->select('id_carrier')
->from('carrier')
->where('name = ' . "'XXX'");
$query->orderBy('id_carrier DESC');
$carrier_id = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getValue($query);
```

Since it's only taking one value, it is working now.